# How can I localize a String using an extension without specifying the table name?

Tags: swift, localization

I want to create an extension to localize my string in a clean way. The details of localization will be within the extension.

Instead of doing this

```swift
String(localized: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications",
       table: "Accessibility")
```

I want to create an extension like this:

```swift
extension String {
   var accesible: String {
      String(localized: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications",
             table: "Accessibility")
   }
}
```

and use like this:

```swift
"\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications".accessible
```

But as long as I'm using string interpolation, I can't do this. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to provide a version of this `String` initializer:

```swift
init(
    localized keyAndValue: String.LocalizationValue,
    table: String? = nil,
    bundle: Bundle? = nil,
    locale: Locale = .current,
    comment: StaticString? = nil
)
```

but with a default `table` of `"Accessibility"`.

```swift
extension String {
    init(localized keyAndValue: String.LocalizationValue,
         bundle: Bundle? = nil,
         locale: Locale = .current,
         comment: StaticString? = nil
    ) {
        self.init(localized: keyAndValue, table: "Accessibility", bundle: bundle, locale: locale, comment: comment)
    }
}
```

Now the line:

```swift
String(localized: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications",
       table: "Accessibility")
```

becomes:

```swift
String(localized: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications")
```

Though to avoid confusion you might want to change the name of the `localized` parameter to `accessibility` or something similar to avoid confusion.

```swift
extension String {
    init(accessibility keyAndValue: String.LocalizationValue,
         bundle: Bundle? = nil,
         locale: Locale = .current,
         comment: StaticString? = nil
    ) {
        self.init(localized: keyAndValue, table: "Accessibility", bundle: bundle, locale: locale, comment: comment)
    }
}
```

Now the line:

```swift
String(localized: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications",
       table: "Accessibility")
```

becomes:

```swift
String(accessibility: "\(accessibilityNotificationNumber) notifications")
```